# How to lsattr directory only?

Tags: xattr

I have a directory called `pub` on a Ubuntu 20.04 server, that I wish to protect from deletion, and I found https://askubuntu.com/questions/504151/how-to-prevent-directory-from-being-deleted-by-user so I tried:

```
$ sudo chattr +i pub
```

Good enough, now I want to check if that attribute has been set:

```
$ lsattr pub
--------------e----- pub/__pycache__
--------------e----- pub/file1.py
--------------e----- pub/file2.py
--------------e----- pub/file3.py
--------------e----- pub/file4.py
```

So, I got the contents of the directory listed, but I did not get the directory listed, which is what I wanted.

I mean, if it at least gave me an entry for `pub`, I would have been fine - but here I get all the *children* and NOT what I requested for... it is so amazingly stupid.

Turns out, there is `lsattr -R` switch for "recursive", which I've expected to provide output like above - but when I run it, it simply also descends into `__pycache__` directory.

So, how do you `lsattr` a directory only, so you can see if you achieved the right thing with `chattr`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `-d`, which [lists directories like other files instead of listing their contents](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/lsattr.1.html):

```
lsattr -d pub
```